# PHP dependency injection - difference between a container, a controller or a factory

Tags: php, dependency-injection, containers, factory

I still cannot tell the difference between a container, a controller or a factory. For instance, the code below, should it be considered as a container, a controller or a factory?

How should it be like if it is a container in this case?

```
namespace ioc
{
    class LoggerContainer
    {
        use \Snippets;

        /*
         * Set props.
         */
        protected $Database;
        public $Logger;

        /**
         * Construct data.
         */ 
        public function __construct($Database) 
        {
            // Set DI.
            $this->Database = $Database;

            // Run private method.
            $this->getLogger();
        }

        /**
         * Set a new class (instantiate the class) as the return result.
         */
        private function getLogger()
        {
            $signature = AUTHENTICATED_USER_SIGNATURE;
            $this->Logger = new \core\model\Logger($this->Database);

            if($_REQUEST['url'] === 'backoffice')
            {
                return $this->Logger->setLogger($signature)->addCategory()->addSomething();
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->Logger->setLogger($signature)->removeSomething();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is a container because it is an object that holds another object that is being accessed, i.e. a Logger in this case.
- A controller is a term that usually refers to the C of the `MVC` and it is what controls the model and the view
- While a factory method refers to a routines that returns the correct specialization of an interface/abstract class

Note that this three terms refer to very different things

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I can understand the first two on container and controller. But not sure about this `returns the correct specialization of an interface/abstract class` - could you please show me an example of a factory?